# Как решить эту проблему в CodeVisionAVR

Tags: avr

Я создаю автоматический звонок в школу.
Урок начинается в 8:30, Продолжительность курса 80 минут, Перерыв 10 минут.

**мой результат**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**мой код**
char hour=0,min=0,sek=0,day=0,month=0,year=0,week_day=0,a_hour=0,a_min=0,/*a_sek=0*/;

```
void show_time() {
///************отображение главного экрана**********//////////
    if((PINC.0==0)&&(ps==0)) {     //переход к настройке времени
        menu=1;
        ps=1;
    }
    if((PINC.3==0)&&(ps==0)) {     //переход к настройке будильника
        menu=3;
        lcd_clear();
        ps=1;
    }

    if(alarm_on==1) {         //пищание будильника

        // 8 : 30 Kirish
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='8')   && (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='8')   && (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='2') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='8')   && (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='3') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='8')   && (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='5') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        // 9 : 50 Chiqish
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='9')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='9')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='2') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='9')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='3') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='9')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='5') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        // 10 : 00 Kirish
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='0')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='0' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='0')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='0' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='2') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='0')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='0' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='3') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='0')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='0' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='5') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }

        // 11 : 20 Chiqish
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='1')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='2' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='1')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='2' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='2') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='1')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='2' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='3') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='1')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='2' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='5') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        // 11 : 30 Kirish
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='1')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='1')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='2') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='1')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='3') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='1')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='5') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        // 12 : 50 Chiqish Katta Tanafus
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='2')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='2')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='3') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='2')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='4') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='2')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='8') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }

        // 13 : 30 Kirish
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='3')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='3')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='2') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='3')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='3') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='3')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='3' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='5') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        // 14 : 50 Chiqish
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='4')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='4')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='2') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='4')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='3') )) {
            PORTC.4=1;
        }
        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='1' && hour%10+0x30 =='4')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='5' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='5') )) {
            PORTC.4=0;
        }



//        if(( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='0')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='0' && min%10+0x30 =='0') && (sek/10+0x30 =='3' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )
//                | ( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='0')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='0' && min%10+0x30 =='1') && (sek/10+0x30 =='0' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') )
//                | ( (hour/10+0x30 =='0' && hour%10+0x30 =='0')   &&  (min/10+0x30 =='0' && min%10+0x30 =='1') && (sek/10+0x30 =='3' && sek%10+0x30 =='0') ) ) {
      PORTC.4=1;     
}

        else {
            PORTC.4=0;

        }



    }

    /////////////////разрешаем обновлять информацию
    if(time_flag==1) {

        rtc_get_time(&hour,&min,&sek);  //считаем время
        rtc_get_date(&week_day,&day,&month,&year);  //считываем дату

        lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
        lcd_putchar(hour/10+0x30);    //выводим часы
        lcd_putchar(hour%10+0x30);
        lcd_putchar(':');
        lcd_putchar(min/10+0x30);     //минуты
        lcd_putchar(min%10+0x30);
        lcd_putchar(':');
        lcd_putchar(sek/10+0x30);     //секунды
        lcd_putchar(sek%10+0x30);

        lcd_gotoxy(0,1);
        lcd_putchar(day/10+0x30);     //дни
        lcd_putchar(day%10+0x30);
        lcd_putchar('/');
        lcd_putchar(month/10+0x30);   //месяцы
        lcd_putchar(month%10+0x30);
        lcd_putchar('/');
        lcd_putchar(year/10+0x30);    //годы
        lcd_putchar(year%10+0x30);

        if(alarm_on==1) {
            lcd_putchar(0);             //вывести значок будильника
        }
        time_flag=0;                  //обнуляем флаг обновления
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через месяц эксплуатации выяснится, что бывают дни с сокращенными уроками

Comment: Портянка из `if`ов доставляет, неужели "в этом" нет переменных?

Answer (score 0):

Хотя на ответ это не тянет,  но в комментариях я писать не могу пока,  увы.
Я не работал с 8й атмегой,  у нас была 128-я. При прошивке на 3 фьюзах должна была стоять галочка. BOOTSZ0, BOOTSZ1,   CKOPTПопробуйте покопать в эту сторону,  возможно проблема в них.
Да, и проверьте настройки порта.  Он же вам пишет,  что COM2 недоступен.  Может,  на вашем компе его просто нет?  Или система его под другим именем знает?  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]